# Dimension of Birman-Murakami-Wenzl Algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, oa.operator-algebras

I was reading the paper *Braids, Link Polynomials and A New Algebra* by J. S. Birman and H. Wenzl, and I was wondering is there a combinatorial way to compute the dimension of the algebras $\mathscr{C}_n(l, m)$ other than comparing the dimension with that of Brauer's centralizer algebra?

I know that using the Bratteli diagram associated to $\mathscr{C}_n(l, m)$ inductively one can solve the problem, but it seems even more difficult to figure out the dimension of each of the simple module a vertex stands for on the $n$-th row than to find the dimension of the algebra...